# access to keychain from app after system update

Tags: ios, xcode, system, keychain

What's happen to data stored in keychain when user update his iOS version to new system ? i.e user have ios 6 and stored some information from my App in Keychain, are those information will be still avaiable after install ios 7 ??

BR
Kivu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will happen to data in KeyChain, keychain persists even after the app is removed, it is linked to AppID and the access rights depend on the **provisioning profile** used when signing your application.

> On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to
>   sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application

Comment: I found this information and this is clear to me, but I'm wondering if there may be any problem after system update with my app data ?

Comment: The problem here is that there is no documentation that backs up the statement "keychain persists even after the app is removed". It currently works that way, but it is not guaranteed to work in future versions of iOS. So the question is, can You rely on it?

Comment: @AndreasPaulsson agree, but logically I don't think this will happen, because by this Apple will kill a good amount of applications in AppStore after updating the iOS.

Comment: @null I agree as well, but they have done this before (e.g. MAC address). I just don't like that they have refused to document keychain items lifetime. The only reason (AFAIK) not to document a well known behaviour is that it will change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After my customers upgraded to a new version of my App using KeyChain.... under iOS7 they lost all the information.

Comment: no they keychain is preserved. must have been something else. maybe they restored or something